# Nested JSON Response in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have the following models:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sites
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts
```

and

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :accounts
```

I am trying to return a JSON representation of a Site that lists all the Accounts information and the User information nested inside.

I added `as_json` to Site to `:include => [:accounts]` and added the same method to Account to `:include => [:user]` however I don't seem to get that nested output in my response. I only get Site -> Account where Account contains the user_id.

Comment: Are you sure `site.as_json(include: {accounts: {include: :user}})` does not work? I tried this on a similar structure and it works for me.

Comment: This does work. I wasn't nesting the as_json method as you had done.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. `site.as_json(include: {accounts: {include: :user}})`. See more about usage here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html
2. Override `serializable_hash` method. The downside is that every time you will call `to_json` it will kick in, and you may want to serialize `Site` differently each time based on the use case.
3. Create your own custom method on `Site`, e.g. `my_serialized_site` that will return your desired `Hash` structure. Then you can call `site.my_serialized_site.to_json`. You would probably want to also create some scope that includes everything you'd like to include, and then call: `Site.my_all_inclusive_scope.map{|x| x.my_serialized_site.to_json}`

You can also have each object delegate your custom serialization to dependents.

For example:

```
class Site
  scope :my_all_inclusive_scope, -> { includes(accounts: :user) }

  def my_serialized_site
    {id: self.id, accounts: {accounts.map(&:my_serialized_account)}}
  end
end

class Account
  def my_serialized_account
    {id: self.id, user: {user.my_serialized_user}}
  end
end

class User
  def my_serialized_user
    { id: self.id, name: name }
  end
end
```

4. You may want to look at `ActiveModel::Serializer` here:
   https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers
5. Or look at `rabl` here:
   https://github.com/nesquena/rabl